# Running supervisord process as root

Tags: django, python-2.7, supervisord

My goal is to run sudo inside one of the programs:

```
[program:doStaff]
command=sudo python manage.py doStaff
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/doStaff.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/doStaff.out.log
```

Here is [unix_http_server] from supervisord.conf:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock  
chmod=0770
```

Tried to set the supervisord user to root inside supervisord.conf but it didn't help.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. Why do you want to do it? (Although note, this question is not about programming and is off topic for SO.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am running a script which deletes and creates files so I need a user with permissions for it.

Comment: So create a user with permissions to that directory. Don't run as root.